# Value (words) on upload button prevent from clicking it

Tags: html, css

Here is my upload form

```
<div class="view-form">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?=maxFileSize?>"/>
   <input name="files" id="files" type="file" class="ui input-file" style="position:absolute;left:380px;top:200px;"/>

   <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Upload" class="ui-button-orange input-btn"; onclick="upload();" style="position:absolute;left:380px;top:300px;width:350px;height:70px;font-size:30px;font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;"/>
   <iframe name="iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

The text 'Upload' which is on the button makes it so that most of the button can't be clicked, only the edges where there isn't any text. Anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a fiddle? The code you have here seems fine and text inside a button would not effect its click area. Most likely some other element is overlapping the button

Comment: But the problem only started happening when I made the text much larger so it filled out most of the space

Comment: If you're using bootstrap (or something similar) there's a [`disabled`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-disabled) class, which prevents button click action.

Comment: if you can recreate it that will help, its hard to tell from what you posted. You're positioning that input so making the button larger could be moving it into the input area...again its hard to tell without a working example of the issue